Create response for OTHER option in prefilled Google Form
I have a list of products with details submitted through a Form, but then need to allow users to edit the data through a Form later. I know that's not a great explanation, but just know that there is a real reason for what I'm doing here. In order to accomplish this I'm reading the data from the correct row of a spreadsheet and populating a Form with that data then serving a prefilled version of the Form to the user, which they can then use to edit any of the prefilled values. It works great for the majority of the questions except there are two questions that are Multiple Choice but do allow for the "Other:" response. If I pass in one of the real options to the code then it works and the form is prepopulated, but if I try to pass in custom text as users will in the Other: field it doesn't populate.
I need to populate the Other: field of a form response generated by Google Apps Script.
This one works, as "DEFAULT" is one of the options in the set.
function makePrefillForm(){
  const FORM = FormApp.openById("17F_6R7QbxCNrhf3X2ednKIxuKi9rB3YfGhgcpImFEwQ");
  let formResponse = FORM.createResponse();

  let items = FORM.getItems();
  let item = items[0].asMultipleChoiceItem();
  
  let response = item.createResponse("DEFAULT");
  formResponse.withItemResponse(response);
  let url = formResponse.toPrefilledUrl();
  Logger.log(url); 
}

This one doesn't work. "DOT4" isn't an option in the set, but I need to refill that line.
function makePrefillForm(){
  const FORM = FormApp.openById("17F_6R7QbxCNrhf3X2ednKIxuKi9rB3YfGhgcpImFEwQ");
  let formResponse = FORM.createResponse();

  let items = FORM.getItems();
  let item = items[0].asMultipleChoiceItem();
  
  let response = item.createResponse("DOT4");
  formResponse.withItemResponse(response);
  let url = formResponse.toPrefilledUrl();
  Logger.log(url); 
}


Can you share a Minimal Reproducible Sample of the Form you are working on? This way the community can better understand your situation, and also have a way to test the answers they have in mind for you.

Related Google form Multiple Choice Other option not visible when submitted from app script
